# Reads Save Files As null

Tags: java, null, load, save, loading

I'm trying to make a backup program that allows you to choose where you want to backup your files. I'm fine with saving the file location, but reading it is the problem.

Saving Method

```
 public static void write(String importdest) throws IOException {
    // Create some data to write.

    String dest = importdest;

    // Set up the FileWriter with our file name.
    FileWriter saveFile = new FileWriter("Q'sSavesConfig.cfg");

    // Write the data to the file.
    saveFile.write(dest);

    // All done, close the FileWriter.
    saveFile.close();
  }
```

Variable Loading Method

```
public static String read() throws IOException {
    String dest;

    BufferedReader saveFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Q'sSavesConfig.cfg"));

 // Throw away the blank line at the top.
    saveFile.readLine(); 
    // Get the integer value from the String.
    dest = saveFile.readLine();
    // Not needed, but read blank line at the bottom.
    saveFile.readLine(); 

    saveFile.close();

    // Print out the values.
    System.out.println(dest + "\n");
    System.out.println();

    return dest;
  }
```

My main problem is that

> System.out.println(dest + "\n")

prints out "null", but it's supposed to load the information held in "Q'sSavesBackup.cfg"

Could someone please show me how I can fix this?

Comment: I dont know what your code is, but you can use this link to read file properly. [How to read file properly](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml)

Comment: why are there whitespaces/newlines in your destination-string? did you check the file you're writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are skipping the only line that has data:

```
// Throw away the blank line at the top.
saveFile.readLine();
```

so then you will reach the `EOF` and the `String` `dest` will equal `null` on the next read:

```
dest = saveFile.readLine();
```

By *not* skipping the first line, you will read back the `String` from file.